# Automatic price conversion

Tags: price, currency

Should price conversion, using the built in conversion rates automatically show the converted price on the frontend?

I have a website with 5 storeviews each with a different currency.

When using the currency converter, the currency symbol changes correctly i.e. to dollars, pounds etc but the value doesnt change.  For example a product costing 29 will be 29 in dollars and pounds.  But not converted as would expect

Comment: Have you imported all the currency rates via the admin section?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you have imported the currency rates via the admin section under `System->Manage Currency->Rates`

Here you can select where to import the rates from or simply add your own values.

After setting up values here you should get all your prices displaying in the correctly converted rates.

Answer (score 1):

afaik is the Magento currency rate importer still broken?

[@anna-volkl implemented an alternative based on the rates of the ECB (European Central Bank)](https://github.com/LimeSoda/LimeSoda_CurrencyConverter)